# ¿Como detectar versiones viejas de navegadores?

Tags: javascript, html5, navegador-web

En mi desarrollo actual quiero mostrar un mensaje si mis librerías no son compatibles con las versiones de lo navegadores. Estoy utilizando axios v0.18.0, jquery v3.3.1, vuejs v2.5.17, lodash v4.17.11 y materialize v1.0.0.

IE 11 hacia abajo se que no acepta mi código por las funciones arrow ( => ), al hacer peticiones asíncronas o en base a promesas.

Safari No es soportado por vue de la version 10.10 hacia abajo.

Etc.

Quisiera en estos casos (cuando el navegador no tiene soporte en las librerías que uso). Sacar un mensaje donde le recomiende a mis usuarios que deben de instalar una versión actualizada de su navegador o que utilicen chrome o firefox.

Para esto tengo un código que lee la versión del navegador.

```js
 var getBrowserInfo = function() {
            var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
            M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
            
            if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
                tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
                return 'IE '+(tem[1] || ''); 
            }
            if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
                tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
                if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
            }
            M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
            if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);

            return M.join(' ');
        };

        let a = getBrowserInfo();
        
        console.log(a)
```

Pero lo que no se que mensaje regresa cuando se ejecuta por ejemplo en IE6 o cuando se ejecuta en Safari 9.

Entonces lo que necesito saber es como el código va a regresar el nombre del navegador para que lo ponga en mi lista de excepciones.

Comment: Si es duplicado? yo estoy preguntando prácticamente como se llaman las versiones obsoletas de los navegadores.

Comment: El código muestra cómo obtener la versión. El que sea obsoleta o no lo determinas tú mismo. Lo que para unos es *obsoleto*  para otros no lo es.

Comment: Exacto, no se como se llaman las versiones que para mi no funcionan, por lo que formule la pregunta.

Comment: En la opcion de ayuda de los navegadores
-informacion del nombredelnavegador

Comment: la lista de user agents -> http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php , un script que identifica navegador y versión -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13480430/1423096

Answer (score 0):

Este código de javascript devuelve el browser y la versión:

```
var browser = '';
var browserVersion = 0;

if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Opera';
} else if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'MSIE';
} else if (/Navigator[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Netscape';
} else if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Chrome';
} else if (/Safari[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Safari';
    /Version[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    browserVersion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
} else if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Firefox';
}
if(browserVersion === 0){
    browserVersion = parseFloat(new Number(RegExp.$1));
}
alert(browser + "*" + browserVersion);
```

Traducido de Chamika Sandamal [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754080/how-to-get-exact-browser-name-and-version)

Un saludo

Comment: gracias mi código hace lo mismo, lo que no se es como se llaman las versiones viejas de los navegadores para cargar mi mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto [este enlace](http://browserhacks.com/), específicamente la sección "Check for Internet Explorer version". Ahí podés encontrar métodos para aplicar estilos o ejecutar funciones únicamente en las versiones a las que querés apuntar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He revisado la pagina y me da una idea de como pueden venir los nombres de los navegadores a los cuales no les daré soporte. buscaba una lista tipo 
Firefox 12, Firefox 13,Firefox 14,Opera 4, etc. Pero me imagino que tendré que instalar las viejas versiones de los navegadores para sacar los nombres que se obtiene mediante javascript